# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybullet' even after installing PyBullet

Tags: pybullet

I have installed pybullet with

```
!pip install pybullet
```

It shows a warning:

```
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead
```

But otherwise installed successfully.

However when in later code when I try to import it as

```
import pybullet as p
```

It shows the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybullet'
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you figured out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the code? The warning pip gave you when you ran pip as root may well be relevant. If you install a library as root with pip, i.e.

```
sudo pip install numpy
```

Then you may not have access to that library in a Python program you write, unless you run it as root as well.

```
python simple-numpy-program.py # probably fails
sudo python simple-numpy-program.py # probably runs
```

This being said, pip is correct, you generally should not run it as root. Why don't you just make a new virtual environment for your project, and install pybullet there?

```
python -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install pybullet
```